# camel cxf:rsServer tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cxfrs

I am having a query regarding camel cxf-rs endpoint implementation in Apache Tomcat.

I have implemented a cxf-rs endpoint in camel to perform a function. What I have basically done is create a route from the cxf-rs endpoint to a bean which is a Java class with some functionality.

So on hitting the cxf-rs endpoint url, the code in my class is executed.

My code looks something like this,the endpoint is,

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:8080/integration/services/rest"
          serviceClass="com........BeginFunction"/>
```

BeginFunction.java:

```
@Path("/mapper/")

 public class BeginFunction {
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

public BeginFunction() {
}

@GET
public Response getMapper() {

    return Response.status(200).entity("getMapper is called").build();

}
 }
```

Route is as follows:

```
                   <route streamCache="true">
                     <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer" />
                     <to uri="myBean"/>
                    </route>
```

Now the implementation seems to work fine in Tomcat only when I have jetty-jars included!! My concern is I dont want another container inside tomcat. So is there any way I can get the endpoint implemented in Tomcat without including the jetty jars.

I am currently running camel 2.11.1, Apache Tomcat 7 and Jetty-bundles-repository-7.6.12.v20130726.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Jetty as Http engine, you can just leverage the [servlet transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) that CXF provides.